# What will be the pandas equivalent of the following altair transformation?

Tags: python, pandas, altair, vega-lite, vega

I've been trying to create a parallel set chart with the help of altair, but am unable to understand what the below mentioned code means, esp. the transform_window function. I've looked up the documentation both on altair as well as vega, but still ain't got a clue as to what it means?

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.iris()

alt.Chart(source).transform_window(
    index='count()'
).transform_fold(
    ['petalLength', 'petalWidth', 'sepalLength', 'sepalWidth']
).mark_line().encode(
    x='key:N',
    y='value:Q',
    color='species:N',
    detail='index:N',
    opacity=alt.value(0.5)
).properties(width=500)
```

Here's what I've tried,

```
df= source.copy()
cols= df.columns.tolist()
df= df.groupby(cols, as_index= False).size()
df= pd.melt(df, id_vars= ["species", "size"], value_vars= ["sepalLength", "sepalWidth", "petalLength", "petalWidth"])

df.reset_index(inplace= True)
df
```

What makes it even more confusing is why index has been set to Nominal when is uses count aggregation(and hence should be qualitative by nature). What will be pandas equivalent of the same, as i'm not so keen on learning these transformations, and find pandas to be a better alternative for data manipulations.

Code Source- https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/parallel_coordinates.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to reproduce the plot with *pandas* and *matplotlib*, using *seaborn* to get the dataset:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

# transpose the measurement columns to rows
iris_measures = iris.iloc[:, 0:4].T

# sort rows alphabetically by measurement name
iris_measures = iris_measures.reindex(sorted(iris_measures.index), axis=0)

# define colormap for the plot legend
colors = {'setosa': 'steelblue',
          'versicolor': 'darkorange',
          'virginica': 'indianred'}

# plot one line for each row
ax = iris_measures.plot.line(color=iris.species.map(colors), linewidth=0.7, legend=True)

# filter legend entries down to one per species
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles[::50], iris.species[::50]);
```

[image: reconstructed lineplot]